# unresolved reference createNotificationChannel()

Tags: android, android-notifications

I try to create a 'O' notification mechanism. So I followed the explanation from Android doc.

I first added the right lib in my gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2"
}
```

And I wrote the following code:

```
private var notification: NotificationCompat? = null

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
        // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
        val name = getString(R.string.channel_name)
        val description = getString(R.string.channel_description)
        val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        val channel = NotificationChannel(PrinterApplication.CHANNEL_ID, name, importance)
        channel.description = description
        // Register the channel with the system
        val notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channel.id)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.print)
            .setContentTitle(resources.getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(resources.getString(R.string.print_service_running))
            .build()
    } else {
        ...
    }
```

And so AS3 reports the following problems:

```
Unresolved reference: createNotificationChannel(channel)
Type Mismatch: required: NotificationCompat? found: Notification!
```

What's the problem please?

Comment: build() gives you the Notification object, not NotificationCmpat moreover for 'O' you just need to create channel other than that everything will work like it was working earlier so you can remove your else control.

Comment: @Harshkurra, Ok thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get rid of the `Unresolved reference: createNotificationChannel`

by declaring `notificationManager` like this:

`val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager`

and `build()` returns a Notification object, not NotificationCompat.

[Context.getSystemService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSystemService(java.lang.String))

[build](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#build())